# ExoPlayer audio/video out of sync

Tags: android, synchronization, exoplayer

While using [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) that on some devices, the audio lags behind the video by about 100ms.  It is usually not noticeable, however for my application I require that the AV sync be perfect.

These devices include the MotoG/X, Nexus S, and HTC Desire.

How can I play the audio track sooner?

Comment: Show us the code you are using to decode the streams and someone might be able to show you how to fix it.

Comment: It is observed in exoplayer sample app aswell

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @Stefan unfortunately not.  Likely due to some phone specific and low level HW issue.